# $_POST for text in DIV elements

Tags: php

Because of my web style, i don't want to use `input` & `textarea` and get information by using `$_POST[]`  and i need to get information that is in DIV element.

For example , I want to get information in this :

```
<div class="mine" name"myname">
this is information that i want to get and put into database by PHP ! 
</div>
```

and :

```
$_POST[myname];
```

But i can't do it with $_POST , How can i do it ??

And if this method can't do this , do you know any other method to get information from DIV like this ?

Comment: You can use `jQuery` to achieve that.

Comment: Use JavaScript to post that information to PHP if you do not want to use the standard forms way

Comment: better way to use ajax

Comment: As far as i now, divs do not hold postable content, at least not with plain HTML, JavaScript can do that. But why dont you just style your input areas as you want?

Comment: @Rikesh thanks. How can i do ? please give me an Example.

Comment: @YUNOWORK this design is different. and can't use that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method. First, with javascript get content of `<div>`

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('DIV1');
</script>

<body>
     <div id="DIV1">
          //Some content goes here.
     </div>
</body>
```

And with ajax send this var to page with `get` or `post` method.

Answer (score 6):

you can call a `onsubmit` function and make a hidden field at the time of form submission like this

**HTML**
need to give a id to your form `id="my_form"`

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="my_form">
<div class="mine" name"myname">
this is information that i want to get and put into database by PHP ! 
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**Jquery** call on submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#my_form").on("submit", function () {
        var hvalue = $('.mine').text();
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='myname' value=' " + hvalue + " '/>");
    });
});
```

**PHP** : submit.php

```
echo $_POST['myname'];
```

Comment: thanks, but an error is in submit.php :  _Notice: Undefined index: myname in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\submit.php on line 2_

Comment: @user3271403 include the jquery library file in your html page

Answer (score 2):

You would need some JavaScript to make that work, e.g. using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$.post('http://example.org/script.php', {
  myname: $('.mine').text()
});
```

It submits text found inside your `<div>` to a script of your choosing.

Comment: thanks, can u give me an example please in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following structure;

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your_url",
            method: "POST",
            data: "myname=" + $(".mine").text(),
            success: function(response) {
                //handle response
            }
        })
    })

})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mine" name"myname">
this is information that i want to get and put into database by PHP ! 
</div>

<input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
```

You can see a simulation here: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/2scaJ/**

Answer (score 0):

Do this in jquery

```
$('.mine').text();
```

and post data using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content of DIV in a variable like below:

```
var x = document.getElementById('idname').innerHTML;
```