# failing get the data on the next php site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Having script in jQuery and PHP (default value) which changes text between brackets of my `<div></div>`but I tried everything to post this text to another site, with no success.
In PHP, saving to document gives nothing, using PHP with post from form, also shows nothing. Text is changed instantly when some change input, and its not saved anywhere on website.

My div is like this

```
<div id="answer_222" class="form-control" style="width: 100px;" disabled="disabled">
```

my script is like this:

```
<script>
function checkValue(input) {
console.log(input.value);
if (input.value > 10000) {
     return input.value = 10000;
  } else if (input.value < 499){
     return input.value = 500;
  }  else {
     return input.value;
  } 
}

$("#num1, #num2").focusout(function() {
    $("#answer").html('');
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    if (num2 > 10000) {                                
        $.alert({
            title: 'Alert',
            content: 'Alert',
                                    });
        num2 = 10000;       
    } else if (num2 < 500 ) {
        $.alert({
title: 'Alert',
content: 'Alert',
        });
    num2 = 500;
    } 
    else {
    num2;
    }
    var answer = num2 / num1;
   answer = answer.toFixed(5);
   $("#answer, #answer_212, #answer_222, #answer_2222").text(answer);
</script>
```

Comment: could you please share the php code as well?

Comment: its not really important php script, just get content from another site <?php url= .... the site where to save the content from this script will also just content echo of the value. But still I cant figure how to resolve this

Comment: @JanGabbaGabriel where is the codes that send the data to another php site? what we see here is just changing of value in a input and alerting? u got to give us the full story in order to help u.

Comment: i tried to send it via php <form method="post" action="test2.php"><div> is in the form, ofcourse with button to submit, but its not show on other site nothing.. maybe I missing the point, how to store the value which changes in div to variable which I need on other site

Comment: The contents of divs are not sent in a POST request, they are not input fields. They are just for display. If you want your values to be sent as part of a normal form postback, you need to place them into a suitable form field such as a textbox or hidden field. Your javascript code, apart from the fact it happens to be the code which puts data into the divs (and therefore could be used to also put data into form fields), is completely irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1 for a list of control types whose values get submitted when a form submit event happens (assuming they are contained within, or associated with, the form being submitted)

Comment: are you able to send me simple script, or anything which this will do? By the way, I tried also to set changed value to hidden input and than send it by form post to another side, but also did not worked for me. ex: <input hidden id="answer_2222" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>" /> on other side I requested be means which I tryed _POST, _GET, _REQUEST , and nothing worked for me, just showed the default value, which wasnt changed by the jquery, but I need also default and if the value will be changed than value to jquery

Comment: "which this will do" Will do what? You just need to create some actual form fields and put your data into those as well as / instead of your divs

Comment: " just showed the default value, which wasnt changed by the jquery" well then you need to make your jquery change it, same way as you change your divs...I thought I already explained that when I said "could be used to also put data into form fields".

Comment: I got it !!!
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621568/post-for-text-in-div-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to put a form in your page the only way to send data to the server is by the HTTP protocol.

So once you append the data to the div you can add an Ajax call to the page with data you want to send in your example *answer*.

The code will look like :

```
$.ajax({
   url : your_url,
   type: post/get,
   data : answer,
   success: function(html) {
    //put something here
  }
});
```

Comment: You can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) all you need to know about ajax and Asynchronous server calls.

Comment: Just a little technical note: _"I assume that you don't want to put a form in your page the only way to send data to the server is by the HTTP protocol."_ It's the same if you _do_ have a form, the data is still sent via HTTP. All communication with a webserver is via HTTP, because the very definition of a webserver is a server which talks HTTP. The only difference using ajax vs a form is the exact way in which the HTTP request is triggered, and how the response is handled.

Comment: I get as far as to save the number to document `  function save(){
 var response=document.getElementById("response");
 var data = 'data='+document.getElementById('answer_222').innerHTML;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     response.innerHTML='<a href="files/'+xmlhttp.responseText+'.txt">'+xmlhttp.responseText+'.txt</a>';
   }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","save.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); xmlhttp.send(data);
}`